# DAX rolling monthly average

Tags: average, dax, rolling-computation

I have a measure that uses a start and end date to calculate the total number of people employed in a month.  I would like to use this measure to produce a rolling 12 month average.  This is my measure: -

```
VAR _FirstDate = MIN ( 'Dates'[Date] )
VAR _LastDate = MAX ( 'Dates'[Date] )
VAR _Filter =
    FILTER (
        'Employment',
        'Employment'[Start] <= _LastDate
            && (
                ISBLANK ( 'Employment'[End] )
                    || 'Employment'[End] >= _FirstDate
            )
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Employment'[id] ), _Filter )
```

If I matrix the measure using a date table with month/year in Power BI I would get this:

| Month Year | Employed |
| --- | --- |
| Jan-20 | 10 |
| Feb-20 | 9 |
| Mar-20 | 12 |
| Apr-20 | 15 |
| May-20 | 16 |
| Jun-20 | 15 |
| Jul-20 | 14 |
| Aug-20 | 16 |
| Sep-20 | 16 |
| Oct-20 | 17 |
| Nov-20 | 16 |
| Dec-20 | 16 |

I cannot simply average the raw data as I need a snapshot of what the employed number was each month.
Is there a way in DAX to generate this table as a variable table and then average the Employed column, which in this example would give me an average of 14.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to achieve what I needed using this DAX: -

```
VAR _FirstDate =
    FIRSTDATE ( STARTOFMONTH ( DATEADD ( Dates[Date], -1, YEAR ) ) )
VAR _LastDate =
    MAX ( Dates[Date] )
VAR _Total =
    AVERAGEX (
        SUMMARIZE (
            FILTER ( ALL ( Dates ), [Date] >= _FirstDate && [Date] <= _LastDate ),
            Dates[Month Year Name Short],
            "Total", [My Measure]
        ),
        [Total]
    )
RETURN
    _Total
```

I'm conscious that this may not be the most efficient way of achieving this so any suggestions are welcome.